# NSUserDefaults not being set

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

This is my code in AppDelegate.m **-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:**

```
//  set color scheme
SingletonColorScheme *colorScheme = [SingletonColorScheme sharedColorScheme];  //  initialize

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if(colorScheme.colorScheme == nil)
    [defaults setObject:@"Saori" forKey:@"colorScheme"];
else
    [defaults setObject:colorScheme.colorScheme forKey:@"colorScheme"];

[defaults synchronize];  //  write them to disk

colorScheme.colorScheme = [defaults objectForKey:@"colorScheme"];  //  set the singleton

NSLog(@"\n\nAppDelegate - colorScheme: %@\ndefault: %@\n\n", colorScheme.colorScheme, [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"colorScheme"]);
```

The NSLog shows this:

```
AppDelegate - colorScheme: 
default: (null)
```

I know now that the code is not correct, but for the life of me, I don't see what's wrong.  I would appreciate some help fixing this!  :D

SD
**UPDATED:**  changed key for NSLog

Comment: It looks like you're trying to write an object of type SingletonColorScheme to NSUserDefaults. That's not a thing it knows how to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stringForKey:@"Saori"
```

should be

```
stringForKey:@"colorScheme"
```

-- you want to get the object for the key that you used previously.

Comment: @spokane-dude try `objectForKey:` then. (Oh, and are you sure you changed the right line?)

Comment: I see the problem:  colorScheme.colorScheme is NOT nil... have to figure out why, because it should be... I'll get back to you...

Comment: Fixed that and now it works... thanks for your help... I appreciate it.  SD